# how to create month and year columns using regex and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Hello Stack overflow Community

I've got the Data Frame here

```
code        sum of August 
AA             1000         
BB             4000           
CC             72262
```

So there are two columns ['code','sum of August']

I've to convert this dataFrame into ['month', 'year', 'code', 'sum of August'] columns

```
month    year    code    sum of August
   8     2020     AA      1000
   8     2020     BB      4000
   8     2020     CC      72262
```

So the ['sum of August'] column sometimes named as just ['August'] or ['august'].  Also sometimes, it can be ['sum of November'] or ['November'] or ['november'].

I thought of using regex to extract the month name and covert to month number.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use dictionary for storing key as number and value as month name as months will be constant

Comment: Hello @Karthik, But how do I extract the month name from the column name?

Answer (score 6):

You can do the following:

```
month = {1:'janauary',
2:'february',
3:'march',
4:'april',
5:'may',
6:'june',
7:'july',
8:'august',
9:'september',
10:'october',
11:'november',
12:'december'}
```

Let's say your data frame is called **df**. Then you can create the column **month** automatically using the following:

```
df['month']=[i for i,j in month.items() if j in str.lower(" ".join(df.columns))][0]


  code  sum of August  month
0   AA           1000      8
1   BB           4000      8
2   CC          72262      8
```

That means that if a month's name exists in the column names in any way, return the number of this month.

Comment: This is brilliant and easy. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to convert month names to their numbers, and the columns can be uppercse or lowercase.
This might work:

```
months = ['january','febuary','march','april','may','june','july','august','september','october','november','december']
monthNum = []#If you're using a list, just to make this run
sumOfMonths = ['sum of august','sum of NovemBer']#Just to show functionality
for sumOfMonth in sumOfMonths:
  for idx, month in enumerate(months):
    if month in sumOfMonth.lower():#If the column month name has any of the month keywords
      monthNum.append(str(idx + 1)) #i'm just assuming that it's a list, just add the index + 1 to your variable.
```

I hope this helps! Of course, this wouldn't be exactly what you do, you fill in the variables and change append() if you're not using it.